How to find the ssh connection behind a reverse tunnel from the server side?
I use the the ssh -R command to create a ssh reverse tunnel in the client side:
ssh -fNR 3389:127.0.0.1:3389 user@remotehost

In the client side, I can use the ps and netstat commands  to find the ssh connection and the corresponding pid, local port and remote port behind the reverse tunnel by
sudo ps aux | grep "-fNR 3389:"

I was wondering if is there a way to find the same local port and remote port from the server side ? Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Use ps -ef | grep pid can get the parent process of the port-listenning process.
See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/513480/get-source-ip-from-reverse-ssh-tunnel

You could use
ss -tulpn | grep ':3389'  # Get the pid of the connected process

You get something like

tcp   LISTEN 0      128                       0.0.0.0:3389       0.0.0.0:*    users:(("sshd",pid=9959,fd=7))

Use this pid in
ss -tp | grep -E 'pid=9959'

You get something like

ESTAB      0      0                                 192.168.1.84:ssh                              192.168.1.52:33452        users:(("sshd",pid=9959,fd=4),("sshd",pid=9952,fd=4))

Btw.
Your sudo ps aux | grep "-fNR 3389:" only shows the executed command with parameters, but this wouldn't work if you use a script or ssh/config for forwarding.

Thanks. But the first command  only shows which programm is listening the port 3389. I want to know which program hold the ssh conncetion that "supports" the port listening since sometimes I must kill the port listening program and restart it agian but the ssh connections are not killed. My server has only a little RAM and a lot of ssh connections will exhaust it.
